# twilio outbound sms , trigger service function on before send to validate

Tags: twilio

Need to create either a service, studio function or TwiML. My requirement is
to identify the recipient, whether the recipient is VoIP or not VoIP.
if the Number is Voip, then the message will not send and the message will return to the user.

Comment: My problem is different.
Message are sending by an android app. I need to put a trigger "Before SMS send" which I can filter to only Non_Voip Number.
Voip Number will be returned to sender app in failure of using personal number rather than Voip.
I already created function to identify non-voip number who uses Lookup api.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twilio Lookup API Line Type Intelligence package](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api/line-type-intelligence) will allow you to determine the line type:

> **Line Type Intelligence**
>
> Lookup's Line Type Intelligence package allows
> you to get the line type of a phone number including mobile, landline,
> fixed VoIP, non-fixed VoIP, toll-free, and more.

Your service will receive the inbound call, use the Lookup API, and use the [Type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api/line-type-intelligence#type-property-values) property for your business logic to either hangup the call or allow the call to proceed.

Comment: it need to trigger before Sending any outbound sms , not call.

Comment: I understand lookup api and already scriptted that part but i do not know how to attach this with Before SMS send event.

Comment: You can use the Twilio Lookup API by supplying a phone number before you generate an outbound call or before you generate an sms. Create a function that uses the Lookup API, you supply whatever phone number you are checking, your function receives the response from the Lookup API, and then your function runs the business rules and if permitted sends the outgoing SMS. There are quickstart tutorials: https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/quickstart